# How can I change the CHANGE ME text inside my script

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried this code on my pc and it doesn't work, does anyone know why?

There is this paragraph that contains the text CHANGE ME. It contains an id of "warning", now I want to change that text when someone clicks on the login button. It does not work on my pc. What am I doing wrong?

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html style="height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0;">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    
    <body style="display: flex; height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0;">
    <!-- maxlength="20"> -->
    
    <form style="margin: auto; border: solid; padding: 10px;">
        
        <label style="font-size: 40px;"> Welcome! </label>
        <br>
        <input id="passwordText" type="password" placeholder="Password" maxlength="20">
        <input id="loginButton" type="button" value="Login" onclick="submit()">
        <br>
        <p id="warning">CHANGE ME</p>
    
    </form>
    
    <script>
    
        function toggleWarningText(text)
        {
            document.getElementById('warning').innerHTML = text;
        }
    
        function submit()
        {
            //toggleWarningText("");

            let password = document.GetElementById("passwordText").value;

            //This togglewarningtext doesn't work
            toggleWarningText(password);
    
            //This below doesn't work either
            if(password.length < 4)
            {
                toggleWarningText("The password must be at least 4 characters long");
            } 
            else 
            {
                toggleWarningText(password);
            }    
        }
    
    </script>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: `document.GetElementById` -> `document.getElementById`, case matters

Comment: @HaoWu THANK YOU, you have helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change submit() function name.
It calls form submit() function.

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html style="height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0;">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    
    <body style="display: flex; height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0;">
    <!-- maxlength="20"> -->
    
    <form style="margin: auto; border: solid; padding: 10px;">
        
        <label style="font-size: 40px;"> Welcome! </label>
        <br>
        <input id="passwordText" type="password" placeholder="Password" maxlength="20">
        <input id="loginButton" type="button" value="Login" onclick="clicked()">
        <br>
        <p id="warning">CHANGE ME</p>
    
    </form>
    
    <script>
    
        function toggleWarningText(text)
        {
            document.getElementById('warning').innerHTML = text;
        }
    
        function clicked()
        {
            //toggleWarningText("");

            let password = document.getElementById("passwordText").value;

            //This togglewarningtext doesn't work
            toggleWarningText(password);
    
            //This below doesn't work either
            if(password.length < 4)
            {
                toggleWarningText("The password must be at least 4 characters long");
            } 
            else 
            {
                toggleWarningText(password);
            }    
        }
    
    </script>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: for some reason your code works, but my code doesn't when I change the submit() into clicked() on both (function and button)
https://pastebin.com/eQxzcfAE
Please help

Comment: Please someone help me, I'm stuck with this part

Comment: This helps = document.GetElementById -> document.getElementById, case matters – answered by Hao Wu

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for

```
function toggleWarningText(text)
    {
        document.getElementById('warning').value= text;
    }
```

instead of .innerHTML

Comment: `HTMLParagraphElement`'s `value` attribute does nothing in this case.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I guess I haven't used vanilla JS for DOM elements enough.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't help with my situation